# Scrolling to next element in container - almost there

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollto, listitem

I'm struggling with a jquery problem.

I think I am close to a solution but I keep stumbling at the moment.

**So my markup (simplyfied) looks like this:**

```
<div class="col">
    Content
   <div class="scroll-container">
      <ul>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>Content</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
<a href="#" class="scroll">scroll down</a>
</div>
```

Basically a .col that holds a **container** and a **button**.

---

### The Plan:

1) After a click on the button container should scroll down to the next `<li>`.

2) When the last `<li>` is reached it **scrolls to the first** `<li>` again. So I need a **loop**.

3) The **numbers** and **size** of `<li>` may change from case to case. *So basically the button should just scroll the next `<li>` to the top of the container.*

4) The scrolled `<li>` needs to have a little margin to the top edge of the container.

---

### Where I am:

I had a similar problem which got brilliantly solved by [ronalchn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1578925/ronalchn) and since the problem is somewhat similar I have created a fiddle based with his code.

[Fiddle with the solved problem](http://jsfiddle.net/fFAQY/) (To see the code in action)

**[Fiddle with the this problem](http://jsfiddle.net/UQsv9/5/)** (Obviously doesn't work with the same jquery)

I think the code basically only **needs a little rearranging to work** with the new situation.

I have tried for a couple of hours but it seems like this is still beyond my current level of understanding jquery.

I am very greatfull for any push in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe fix your fiddle so that the scrollable content is visible.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only post 2 links at the moment, so here it is: [Fiddle with scrollable elements visible](http://jsfiddle.net/UQsv9/5/) I hope it helps.

Comment: I edited your post to swap the links, in order to better help future questers. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/UQsv9/7/

CSS changes: added `position: relative` to your `ul`

I'm using `$.fn.data` to store the current child, from there it's just using the difference between the two offsets to calculate the new `top`.

Comment: Wow, amazing work! I didnt expect to get a solution so quick! Thank you  @Royce ! I havent worked with "$.fn.data" yet, so I guess I have much to learn. :-) Thank you for the //comments. Helps me a lot with the understanding! All the best to you.

Comment: Hi @Royce Feng, unfortunately I got an **"Uncaught TypeError"** while implementing the code. I had to update the class-names, but left everything else untouched. [fiddle - updated classnames](http://jsfiddle.net/UQsv9/8/). Here is a live example from my site: [Live example](http://kanido-workspace.de/sandbox) Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You moved your scroll button within a `<p>`, you'll need to change `var container = $(this).siblings('.scroll-container').find('ul');` to `var container = $(this).parent().siblings('.scroll-container').find('ul');`